# How to write text to a cell after checking if file exists in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I am checking if a file exists in a folder and if yes, instead of a message box, I would like to write text (e.g. "Extracted") in a cell. The code works fine the message box, but once I try to replace those with actual cells, nothing gets written. Any idea what is happening?

```
Dim FileName As String

FileName = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ExtractFolderPath & ExtractFileName)

If FileName = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12), 4).Value = ""
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12), 4).Value = "Extracted"
End If
```

Comment: 5 questions and only 1 has an accepted answer. Please fix that if you have received useful answers to your questions.

Comment: Update: since the code is part of a larger SAP scripting code, and there is a constant switch between Excel/SAP/Windows dialog, it might have been selecting wrong screens. Once I moved the code from the function that ran the main portion of the code up into a sub that initiated it, the code worked.

Comment: @vlad_milovanovic So the error was `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12).Value` You could also have specify `Sheets("Name")` and not change the place of this line of code

Comment: @vlad_milovanovic if my answer helped you to solve your issue may I ask you to accept it ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said that your `if` statment is working fine with `MsgBox` Maybe the error is here.

Give this code a try  :

```
Dim FileName As String

FileName = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(ExtractFolderPath & ExtractFileName)

If FileName = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12).Value, 4).Value = ""
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12).Value, 4).Value = "Extracted"
End If
```

Else if this doesn't work you need to be sure that :

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12).Value
```

Is a number so you can I think use this :

```
debug.print IsNumeric(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 12).Value)
```

It should returns you `True`

Answer (score 0):

Try decomposing the problem:

```
Dim FileName As String, rng as range, sh as worksheet

FileName = Dir(ExtractFolderPath & ExtractFileName)
set sh = Thisworkbook.WorkSheets(1)
set rng =  sh.Cells(.Cells(1, 12), 4)
debug.print rng.address, rng.value2
with rng
    If FileName = vbNullString Then
        .Value = ""
    Else
        .Value = "Extracted"
    End If
end with
```